# Instantiate unique instances of a class in another class constructor

Tags: python

I have two classes. One which instantiates the other in its constructor.

```
class Details(object):
    pass

class Overview(object):
    def __init__(self, details = Details()):
        self.details = details
```

When I create two instances of overview, they change the same instance of details. Shouldn't Overview create a new instance of Details() upon every instantiation?

```
ov1 = Overview()
ov2 = Overview()
print(id(ov1.details))
print(id(ov2.details))

# 2940786890344
# 2940786890344
```

Comment: They're both pointing to the default instance (`details = Details()`) since you didn't pass anything to either of the `Overview` constructors.

Comment: Right, but shouldn't the default instance be a new instance of Details? every time the constructor is called, Details is being created, stored in 'details' and then store in self.details.

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The default argument to `details` is evaluated at class creation time! All instances of `Overview` will have the identical `Details` instance if not provided. Change along the lines of:

```
class Overview(object):
    def __init__(self, details=None):
        self.details = Details() if details is None else details
```

This is a common source of surprise for beginners, especially with [mutable default arguments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments).

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, default arguments are evaluated at function definition time, which is well before class creation time (the entire body of the class is executed first).